# PRESTO SQL: How to query value in max datetime in each txn and fill other that not select to null value

Tags: presto

I have raw data that show in the first image and I want to select a max time for each user in po_time compared pr_time. Then select prepaid or postpaid, if you select prepaid and the postpaid should be NULL

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    uid,
    phone_number,
    time,
    CASE WHEN pr_time > po_time THEN telecom_prepaid END AS telecom_prepaid,
    CASE WHEN po_time > pr_time THEN telecom_postpaid END AS telecom_postpaid
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    uid;
```